# Does select * always return the same columns order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, select

E.g., table `t1` has columns `c1` & `c2`, is there any chance that `select * from t1` returns  tuples `(c2, c1)` instead of `(c1, c2)`?

And is there any chance that `select * from (select * from t1)` returns  tuples `(c2, c1)` instead of `(c1, c2)`?

Comment: Never.  The values are returned in the order they are specified in the `SELECT`.  With `*`, it is based on the definition of the table.

Answer (score 2):

It will always return the same columns unless you drop a column and re add it. Then it will appear at the end. To be safe I would list the columns rather than using select *

Comment: Thanks, is there any official doc to confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

In a simple case, selecting from one table, it should be consistent.
When the from includes multiple tables, it can be more complex.

In the following "NATURAL JOIN" example from Oracle, the first column(s) are the columns common to both tables, followed by the columns from the first table specified in the join (other than the common ones), and then those from the second table.

You can get into more complex situations where there are multiple common columns in the tables, in different order in each table, and with more than two tables used in the source....

```
create table tab_a
(id number(2,0) primary key,
value_a varchar2(20));

create table tab_b
(value_b varchar2(20),
id number(2,0) primary key
);

insert into tab_a values (10,'blue');
insert into tab_a values (20,'red');
insert into tab_b values ('square',10);
insert into tab_b values ('oval',20);

select * from tab_b natural join tab_a

         ID VALUE_B              VALUE_A
      10.00 square               blue
      20.00 oval                 red
```

PS. Edit to add - Natural join syntax is a stupid idea, and shouldn't be used in practice. This is one reason why. More generally, if audit style columns get added to tables, such as CREATED_BY, it confuses the heck out of the SQL.